# Can a mobile app page determine what mobile app page called it and what was selected?

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

My issues tracking application has several categories (Client, AssignedTo, Module/Type, Priority, Status, Build, etc). There are several views that have two categorized columns (EG: Client and AssignedTo, Client and Module, AssignedTo and Priority, PPriority and Client,etc.

I am implementing mobile pages using the XPages Mobile controls. I want to streamline things so the the selection of the view on the mobile home page drives to a page for selecting the appropriate first category which, in turn drives to a page for selecting the second category. What I am not figuring out, is once the selection of the first categories value is done, and the second category selection page is open, what the value selected before was?

Here is my sample page so far:

```
<xe:singlePageApp
    id="singlePageApp1"
    selectedPageName="mhome">
    <xe:appPage
        id="appPage1"
        pageName="mhome">
        <xe:djxmHeading
            id="djxmHeading1"
            label="Home">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xe:djxmRoundRectList
            id="djxmRoundRectList1">
            <xe:djxmLineItem
                id="djxmLineItem1"
                label="Issues by Client By Assigned To"
                moveTo="selectClient1">
            </xe:djxmLineItem>
            <xe:djxmLineItem
                id="djxmLineItem2"
                label="Issues by Client By Module"
                moveTo="selectClient2">
            </xe:djxmLineItem>
        </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
    </xe:appPage>
    <xe:appPage
        id="appPage2"
        pageName="selectClient1"
        resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading
            id="djxmHeading2"
            label="Select Client"
            moveTo="mhome"
            back="back">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView
                    var="view1"
                    viewName="ByClientAssignedTo">
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xp:this.data>
            <xe:djxmRoundRectList
                id="djxmRoundRectList2">
                <xp:repeat
                    id="repeat1"
                    rows="30"
                    value="#{javascript:view1.getColumnValues(0);}"
                    var="client"
                    indexVar="clidx">
                    <xe:djxmLineItem
                        id="djxmLineItem3"
                        label="#{javascript:client}"
                        moveTo="selectAssignedTo1">
                    </xe:djxmLineItem>
                </xp:repeat>
            </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:appPage>
    <xe:appPage
        id="appPage3"
        pageName="selectClient2"
        resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading
            id="djxmHeading3"
            label="Select Client (2)"
            moveTo="mhome"
            back="back">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView
                    var="view1"
                    viewName="ByClientAssignedTo">
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xp:this.data>
            <xe:djxmRoundRectList
                id="djxmRoundRectList3">
                <xp:repeat
                    id="repeat2"
                    rows="30"
                    value="#{javascript:view1.getColumnValues(0)}"
                    var="client"
                    indexVar="clidx">
                    <xe:djxmLineItem
                        id="djxmLineItem4"
                        label="#{javascript:client}"
                        moveTo="selectType1">
                    </xe:djxmLineItem>
                </xp:repeat>
            </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:appPage>
    <xe:appPage
        id="appPage4"
        pageName="selectAssignedTo1"
        resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading
            id="djxmHeading4"
            back="back"
            label="Select Assigned To"
            moveTo="selectClient1">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:text
            escape="true"
            id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"What was selected on the previous page?"}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
    </xe:appPage>
</xe:singlePageApp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technique 1:
The djxmLineItem event supports the onClick event event though there is no documentation for it within Xpages (that I have found). It is documented as part of dojo under the dojox.mobile ListItem.

If necessary create an onClick event for another control and copy the code under the xe:djxmLineItem tag. You can use deferred evaluation (#) to access the indexVar to identify which ListItem inside the repeat has been clicked.

A major drawback of adding an event handler is that you must trigger a partial refresh on something inside the target page in order to cause its content to be rendered. This in turn means that pages content must be preloaded in order for the refresh target to be available. This is most likely a bug in the current implementation of mobile controls but it can be a PAIN!.

Technique 2:
To track the pages AND the selected item without the above side effects. DOn't add an event handler. Instead... create the listitem in such a way that the "id" for the item is added as a parameter for the moveTo attribute.

example:

```
<xe:djxmRoundRectList id="menuList">
  <xp:repeat value="#{compositeData.view.listItems}"
    var="listItem" indexVar="menuIndex" id="listRepeat" rows="999">
    <xe:djxmLineItem id="listItem"
      label="#{listItem.label}" moveTo="#{compositeData.view.moveTo}&amp;id=#{listItem.id}&amp;clear=true"
      rightText="#{listItem.rightText}">
    </xe:djxmLineItem>
  </xp:repeat>
</xe:djxmRoundRectList>
```

The following code can be added to the bottom of the page to add an event listener for the transition event of every appPage.

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
          dijit.registry.byClass("extlib.dijit.mobile.View").forEach(function(widget, index, hash){
          dojo.connect(widget, "onBeforeTransitionOut", function(moveTo, dir, transition, context, method){
          var deferred = adminService.setMoveTarget(moveTo);
        });
      });
    });
  ]]>
  </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

The event handler is calling a jsonRpcService that passes the details to a bean (before the page transition occurs).

```
<xe:jsonRpcService id="jsonRpcService1" serviceName="adminService"
  state="true">
  <xe:this.methods>
    <xe:remoteMethod name="setMoveTarget"
      script="AdminSession.setMoveTarget(moveTo);return true;">
      <xe:this.arguments>
        <xe:remoteMethodArg name="moveTo"></xe:remoteMethodArg>
        </xe:this.arguments>
      </xe:remoteMethod>    
  </xe:this.methods>
</xe:jsonRpcService>
```

the setMoveTarget() method in the AdminSession bean should then be able to parse out the parameters to identify the selected item as well as track the page transition.

Note: adding clear=true is a way of ensuring pageContent of a page is only reset when moving forward to a page and not when you move back to the same page.

Comment: ps: The credit for the sample code belongs with Nathan Freeman who developed it a project we are working on together.

Comment: I got technique #1 working quite well, thanks. I will update with the solution code in a bit

Answer (score 1):

So here is the code for the modified approach which works with a this caveat...

1. The views are only categorized on the first column, though that may not be needed. The page uses the "Filter by column value" to show the selected documents. This was because the repeat control for the subcatAppPage would not find multiple values unless I removed the categorization from the view.
2. I used a dataContext control on the page to define the views that would be shown. It needs more complexity but this works for now:

   ```
   <xp:this.dataContexts>
     <xp:dataContext
       var="viewListItems">
       <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
         try {
           var returnVal = [];
           returnVal.push({name:"Issues by Assigned To By Client", alias:"ByAssignedToClient", cats:["AssignedTo","Client"]});
           returnVal.push({name:"Issues by Assigned To By Module", alias:"ByAssignedToType", cats:["AssignedTo","Type"]});
           returnVal.push({name:"Issues by Client By Assigned To", alias:"ByClientAssignedTo", cats:["Client","AssignedTo"]});
           returnVal.push({name:"Issues by Client By Module", alias:"ByClientType", cats:["Client","Type"]});
           return returnVal;
         } catch(e) {
            _dump(e);
         }
       }]]></xp:this.value>
     </xp:dataContext>
   </xp:this.dataContexts>
   ```

Now here is the mobile controls:

```
<xe:singlePageApp
        id="singlePageApp1"
        selectedPageName="mhome">
        <xe:appPage
            id="homeAppPage1"
            pageName="mhome">
            <xe:djxmHeading
                id="djxmHeading1"
                label="Home">
            </xe:djxmHeading>
            <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList1">
                <xp:repeat
                    id="repeat3"
                    rows="10"
                    var="listItem"
                    indexVar="liidx"
                    value="#{viewListItems}">
                    <xe:djxmLineItem
                        id="djxmLineItem5"
                        moveTo="selectCat"
                        label="#{javascript:listItem.name;}">
                        <xp:eventHandler
                            event="onClick"
                            submit="true"
                            refreshId="selectCatPagePanel"
                            refreshMode="partial">
                            <xp:this.action>
                                <xp:actionGroup>
                                    <xp:executeScript script="#{javascript:sessionScope.m_selectedView = listItem;}"></xp:executeScript>
                                </xp:actionGroup>
                            </xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xe:djxmLineItem>
                </xp:repeat>
            </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
        </xe:appPage>
        <xe:appPage
            id="categoryAppPage2"
            pageName="selectCat"
            resetContent="true"
            preload="true">
            <xp:panel id="selectCatPagePanel">
                <xp:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoView var="view1">
                        <xp:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:
try{
    var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
    if(ssview == null) return "ByClientAssignedTo";
    return ssview.alias;
} catch(e) {
    return "ByClientAssignedTo";
}}]]></xp:this.viewName>
                    </xp:dominoView>
                </xp:this.data>
                <xe:djxmHeading
                    id="djxmHeading2"
                    moveTo="mhome"
                    back="back">
                    <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
if(ssview == null) return "Select something";
return "Select " + ssview.cats[0];
}]]></xe:this.label>
                </xe:djxmHeading>
                <xp:text
                    escape="true"
                    id="computedField3">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
if(ssview == null) return "View is nothing"
return "View is: " + ssview.name;
}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
                <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList2">
                    <xp:repeat
                        id="repeat1"
                        rows="30"
                        value="#{javascript:view1.getColumnValues(0);}"
                        var="catvalue"
                        indexVar="catidx">
                        <xe:djxmLineItem
                            id="djxmLineItem3"
                            label="#{javascript:catvalue}"
                            moveTo="selectSubcat">
                            <xp:eventHandler
                                event="onClick"
                                submit="true"
                                refreshId="selectSubCatPagePanel"
                                refreshMode="partial">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
ssview.selectedCat = catvalue
sessionScope.m_selectedView = ssview;
}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xe:djxmLineItem>
                    </xp:repeat>
                </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
            </xp:panel>
        </xe:appPage>
        <xe:appPage
            id="subcatAppPage3"
            pageName="selectSubcat"
            preload="true"
            resetContent="true">
            <xp:panel id="selectSubCatPagePanel">
                
                <xe:djxmHeading
                    id="djxmHeading3"
                    moveTo="selectCat"
                    back="back">
                    <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
if(ssview == null) return "Select something";
return "Select " + ssview.cats[1];}]]></xe:this.label>
                </xe:djxmHeading>
                <xp:text
                    escape="false"
                    id="computedField1">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
if(ssview == null) return "blah blah";
"View is: " + ssview.name +
"<br/>" + ssview.cats[0] + ": " + ssview.selectedCat;
}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
                <xe:djxmRoundRectList id="djxmRoundRectList3">
                    <xp:repeat
                        id="repeat2"
                        rows="10"
                        var="subcatValue"
                        indexVar="catidx">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://var vals = @Unique(view2.getColumnValues(1));
//vals.sort();
var vals = [];
try{
    var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
    if(ssview==null) return vals;
    vals = @DbLookup("", ssview.alias, ssview.selectedCat, 2);
    return @Unique(vals);
} catch(e) {
    return vals;
}
return vals;}]]></xp:this.value>
                        <xe:djxmLineItem
                            id="djxmLineItem1"
                            label="#{javascript:subcatValue}"
                            moveTo="showView">
                            <xp:eventHandler
                                event="onClick"
                                submit="true"
                                refreshId="showViewPagePanel"
                                refreshMode="partial">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
if(ssview == null) return;
ssview.selectedSubcat = subcatValue
sessionScope.m_selectedView = ssview;
}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xe:djxmLineItem>
                    </xp:repeat>
                </xe:djxmRoundRectList>
            </xp:panel>
        </xe:appPage>
        <xe:appPage
            id="viewAppPage4"
            pageName="showView"
            preload="true"
            resetContent="true">
            <xp:panel id="showViewPagePanel">
                <xe:djxmHeading
                    id="djxmHeading4"
                    moveTo="selectSubcat"
                    back="back">
                    <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
if(ssview == null) return "asdaasd";
ssview.name;}]]></xe:this.label>
                </xe:djxmHeading>
                <xp:text
                    escape="false"
                    id="computedField2">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
if(ssview == null) return "blah blah";
"View is: " + ssview.name +
"<br/>" + ssview.cats[0] + ": " + ssview.selectedCat +
"<br/>" + ssview.cats[1] + ": " + ssview.selectedSubcat;
}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
                <xe:dataView
                    id="dataView1"
                    columnTitles="true">
                    <xe:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="view4">
                            <xp:this.viewName><![CDATA[#{javascript:
try{
    var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
    if(ssview == null) return "ByClientAssignedTo";
    return ssview.alias;
} catch(e) {
    return "ByClientAssignedTo";
}}]]></xp:this.viewName>
                            <xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
    var ssview = sessionScope.m_selectedView;
    if(ssview == null) return ["xxx","yyy"];
    if(!ssview.selectedCat) return ["xxx"];
    if(!ssview.selectedSubcat) return [ssview.selectedCat]
    return [ssview.selectedCat, ssview.selectedSubcat];
    //return ssview.selectedCat;
} catch(e) {
    return ["xxx","yyy"];
}}]]></xp:this.keys>
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xe:this.data>
                    <xe:this.summaryColumn>
                        <xe:viewSummaryColumn
                            columnName="Subject"
                            columnTitle="Subject"
                            contentType="text">
                        </xe:viewSummaryColumn>
                    </xe:this.summaryColumn>
                </xe:dataView>
            </xp:panel>
        </xe:appPage>
    </xe:singlePageApp>
```